# Does unzip (and un-other-compress) deserve its own tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

Do we need both the tags [zip](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/zip) and [unzip](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/unzip)?

- Or more generic: should we clean the un-$compress tags to $compress?
- Our should we even consolidate some of these tags into [compression](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/compression)?

Inspired by [this similar post](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/8677/do-unrar-and-unzip-deserve-their-own-tags) on [SU] and seeing a few posts with the [tag unzip](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/unzip) (20 uses).

Comment: A better question might be, are these questions on topic at all?

Answer (score 2):

We only had [unzip](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/unzip), no unrar, gunzip, bunzip2, etc...

[zip](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/zip) could probably use some review for topicality as Michael points out.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree because most of these questions aren't even on-topic. If they are, it's unrelated to the act of zipping/unzipping and instead something else, so the tag isn't even relevant.

Just my two cents.